# Make HTTP connection using GSM network, not WiFi

Tags: android, http, wifi, gsm

I need to make HTTP request on Android using GSM connection, not Wifi.

My current solution is to disconnect from all wi-fi connections and perform a request. Is there any better solution? I could not find any relevant methods in the API (I looked in package `org.apache.http`, but it seems it is completely unaware of what type of connection should be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it seems it is completely unaware of what type of connection should be used

correct - indirection is your friend - Location Services (for example) are just the same

Comment: So, it looks like my current solution is the best in this situation?

Comment: correct, if you need to test a specific provider you have to disable all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Doing as proposed in the question is perfect should the application need to submit the HTTP request thru GSM *now*, at the time it is started or at the time the user triggers this action.

But if the app needs to do submit an HTTP request *when* the connection type is GSM that's a bit different. In that last case I would do that way:

```
private static boolean isOnlineUsingGsm(Context ctx) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectManager = (ConnectivityManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // Return true if connected thru GSM
    return connectManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
}

private void somewhereInTheCode() {
    if (isOnlineUsingGsm(context)) {
        sendHttpRequest();
    }
    // else don't send it
}
```